# How to install bower dependency without specifying version number?

Tags: dependencies, bower

I am trying to install the fittext.js from bower.json, the current version of this library is 1.2.0. However, when I do

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "modernizr": "~2.6.2",
    "jquery": "~1.11.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "skrollr": "~0.6.21",
    "html5media": "~1.1.8",
    "fittext.js": "~1.2.0" 
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

It prompts "**No tag found that was able to satisfy 1.2.0**". How could I install it without specifying version number?

Answer (score 4):

Try using the following configurtion:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "modernizr": "~2.6.2",
    "jquery": "~1.11.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "skrollr": "~0.6.21",
    "html5media": "~1.1.8",
    "fittext": "*" 
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Note that when you're trying to search for any library to install with bower use the following search tool powered by bower:

http://bower.io/search/

Search for the package you want and install it using

```
bower install --save package_name
```